# Banshee and Totem are crashing... How to fix it?

Tags: 11.04, banshee, totem

Both banshee and Totem are crashing as soon as I launch them. Before this I was watching a DVD using totem, the DVD had a lot of scratches, and hence totem crashed. After that whenever I try to launch totem or banshee neither one of them start up. I'm using Natty Narwhal.

Comment: You should try running Banshee from a terminal to look for any errors. Open Terminal, then just type `banshee` and press Enter. Then, copy and paste the output into your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you store your music files on a different partition than Ubuntu is installed on, make sure it is properly mounted.